# Calculate a % of a field

Tags: sql, percentage, presto, delta

Using quicksight, I'd like to create the % of my total revenues vs delta of loss.

Basically, I've a field, where inside there are all the economics (so not just revenues but also costs). I'm successfully filtering it to have 2 columns, one for Revenues and one for costs. Revenues came adding these filters to different categories field I've in the system:

```
Pl_cat --> filtered as "1-revenues" and "2-Expenses"
bu_F --> filtered as "1-work"
Report_super_category --> filters as "1-Coworking"
Act_Bud --> filtered as "Actual"
```

Applying all these filters to fy_total (field that held all my numbers), using a month field for the X axes, and multiplying costs *-1, I get the correct revenues and costs numbers in columns a table split by month.

Also, using fy_total withouth any calcs, I get the delta by month (leaving those filters applied of course).

What i'd to do now is, getting the % of that delta over those filter revenues.

Example: Total month revenues (all fields, no filters): 1M

Applying those filters and a calculated field where Expenses are multiplied by -1, I get the revenues and expenses for 1-Coworking under 1-Work in 2 columns, let's say 600K for Revenues and 400K for expenses.

Also Using fy_total withouth any calculated fyeld, I get its delta: 600K-400K = 200K

I want to transform those 200K in 200/600 = 33%

[image: Actual situation]

I've added an image of my current situation, I'm using quicksight which is also based on SQL presto language

Thank you guys!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in a text table format* would really help other people understand your question.